# display issue with matplot in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix composed of 20 sampled data like this (the original data has 30 observations):

```
## dummy data
dat <- rnorm(30, 1, 0.5)
## generate 20 sampled data
resamples <- lapply(1:20, function(i) sample(dat, replace = T))
## create matrix combining all sampled data together
mat <- t(do.call(rbind, resamples))
```

I want to draw a dot plot showing the change of the 30 observation across the 20 sampled dataset. The `matplot` function seems to work, but it displays numbers and alphabets instead of **points** in the figure:

```
## draw plot
matplot(mat, type = "p", ylab = " ")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? And how can I make the x-axis ranges from 1 to 30, separated by 1? (I tried `xlim` but did not work)

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: `?matplot` holds the answers. *pch: character string or vector of 1-characters or integers for plotting characters, see **?points**. The first character is the plotting-character for the first plot, the second for the second, etc. **The default is the digits (1 through 9, 0) then the lowercase and uppercase letters.***

Comment: use `axis` for your second question `matplot(mat, type = "p", ylab = " ", pch = 1, xaxt = 'n'); axis(1, 1:30)`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail and @rawr! I did not know the use of `pch` function before. This is very helpful!